# How to get the this of a object in a handler for a click event in jquery?

Tags: jquery, scope

```
// begin signals
this.loginSignal

this.init = function(){
  // init signals
  this.loginSignal = new t.store.helpers.Signal;

  // map events
  $('[value]="login"', this.node).click(this.login)
}

this.login = function(){
  // this will dispatch an event that will be catched by the controller
  // but this is not refering to this class
  // and the next line fails :s
  this.loginSignal.dispatch();
}
```

to make it work now i must add

```
var $this = this;
```

this line and use `$this` instead of `this` :S

any clearer way around?
thanks

Comment: on another note, `[value]="login"` should probably be `[value="login"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the click handler is called, the `this` keyword is remapped to the element that triggered the event. To get to the original object, you want to put the function code in a closure, and make a reference to the object outside the closure, where you still have the correct reference to `this`.

```
  // map events
  var thisObject = this;
  $('[value]="login"', this.node).click(function () {
     thisObject.loginSignal.dispatch();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Technique 1: Use a Closure**

```
var me = this;
$(...).click(function(){ me.login(); });
```

**Technique 2: Get the element that handled the event**

```
this.login = function(evt){
  var el = evt.currentTarget || evt.target || evt.srcElement;
  // Do something with the element here.
};
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a method [called `jQuery.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) that is used to return a function with the value of `this` set to what you want.

```
$('[value="login"]', this.node).click( $.proxy(login, this) );
```