# Event handler method of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a problem with variable scope. I am setting event listeners (`onclick`), but the handler is method of an object and I need to refer to the object within the handler method.

Example:

```
var FOO = function () {
 this.clicked = false
};

FOO.prototype.handler = function(e)
{
 this.clicked = true;
}

FOO.prototype.setListeners = function()
{
 $("#but").click(this.handler);
}

var oop = new FOO();
oop.setListeners();
```

Example works to the point `this.clicked = true;` where because `this` doesn't refer to the `oop`.

How do I pass a reference of the object to the handler function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the this of a object in a handler for a click event in jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466524/how-to-get-the-this-of-a-object-in-a-handler-for-a-click-event-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOO.prototype.setListeners = function()
{
    var that = this;
    $("#but").click(function(){that.handler();});
}
```