# obtaining object property from function in method js

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the this of a object in a handler for a click event in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466524/how-to-get-the-this-of-a-object-in-a-handler-for-a-click-event-in-jquery)

I'm trying to create object that will bind few events to another object method. My code is some like this:

```
var MAP = MAP || {}
MAP = {
height: 100
/*
 * rest of code
 */
};
var CONFIG = CONFIG || {}
CONFIG = {
  _MAP : MAP,
  setEvents:function(){
   $('#map').mousedown(function(){
   height = this._MAP.height;
   console.log(height);
  }
};
$(function(){ CONFIG.setEvents(); })
```

and i cant connect height in setEvents method with MAP.height, but when I call this._MAP.height directly from method (not bind to on mouse down) every thing is ok. Can someone help me resolve this problem?

Comment: You should read this (great) article: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: side note - your `height` variable is an implicit global in the mousedown handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function body for `.mousedown` `this` refers to the DOMElement that `$('#map')` found.

In order to keep track of the proper `this`, you want to store it in your closure, outside the call to `.mousedown`.  `var $this = this` in the `setEvents` function, for example.

Comment: To be entirely accurate, it's actually the `DOMElement`, rather than the jQuery object.

Comment: can you show me an example? I don't get it.. EDIT. ohh yes thats right, but how can I fix this?